# Why my const variable change on execution?

Tags: c, linux, gnu

i have a random number generator that should be the same number for all execution, but the number change and is not even of 4 numbers?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    srand(1); 
    int const numero=rand() % 7000 + 1000;
    char *caracter;

    while (scanf("%s",&caracter)!=EOF){
        printf("%i\n",numero);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I use a .txt with random names and the result is this

---

```
masa6144
pupu6144
ogro6144
pelad1oo
pedo0
tucan110
lloron28271
cheso111
```

---

as you can see the three first names have a 4 length number and same but after the 3 all become weird, what can be ?

Comment: Undefined behavior, you are overwriting other variables because you treat the pointer variable as if it was a char array itself. You should see a compiler warning telling you about this problem.

Comment: `%s` format is for null-terminated strings. You can't read it into one character.

Comment: And don't put `&` before `caracter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any halfway decent compiler will tell you that something is wrong. Unfortunately, many compilers default to not telling you if anything is wrong: you need to explicitly turn on warnings. With GCC or Clang, always compile with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`. Also pass a `-O` option unless debugging, because some warnings are omitted without it.

```
$ gcc -O -Wall -Wextra a.c
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:12:21: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat=]
                     while (scanf("%s",&caracter)!=EOF){
                     ^
a.c:6:14: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
              ^
a.c:6:32: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
```

---

> ```
> scanf("%s",&caracter)
> ```

This stores the word typed by the user in the character array that starts at the address `&caracter`. The character array needs to be large enough for the word. If it isn't, C offers no protection. It's a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). The consequences of a buffer overflow can be anything (it's [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)). This can cause a crash if it reaches memory that isn't allocated or that is read-only, but it can also overwrite whatever happens to be located there. The exact behavior tends to depend heavily on the processor, on the compiler, on the surrounding code, how the compiler optimizes it, etc.

Given the behavior you saw, evidently, in your test, `numero` is just after `caracter` in memory, and `caracter` has room for 4 bytes. Note that this is the variable `caracter` itself, not something that `caracter` points to. When you entered `masa`, this filled the four bytes of `caracter`, and wrote a null byte in `numero`. It's no coincidence that 6144 is a multiple of 256. Your platform is [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) (all PC and non-antique Mac are little-endian), so the first byte of the memory representation of `numero` is the least significant byte. Thus the null byte overwrote the least significant byte, making the number a multiple of 256.

I don't know what happened with `pelad1oo` (what did you type?). With `tucan110`, it's clear what happened: you typed `tucan`, which wrote `tuca` to the 4 bytes of `caracter` and `n` and a null byte to the lower two bytes of `numero`, making the value of `numero` `0 * 256 + 'n'` where `'n'` is the value of the character `n`, which in [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is 110. With `lloron`, the overflow into `numero` was `on` and the null byte, making the value `0 * 256 * 256 + 'n' * 256 + 0 = 28271`. And so on.

---

When you pass a pointer to a function, you must always make sure that it's pointing to something (or that it's a null pointer, if the function accepts null pointers). If the function requires an array, you must make sure that the pointer is pointing to a large enough array. If the function writes a string, that's an array of characters with a final null character.

The simple thing to do is to make `caracter` a large enough array.

```
char caracter[100];
…
scanf("%99s", caracter);
```

Note that there's no `&` before `caracter`: when an array is used as a value, it's automatically converted to a pointer to the beginning of the array. And note the `99` in `%s`: that's the maximum number of characters which `scanf` will write to `caracter` (plus one null character to end the string). Note that if `scanf` writes a 99-character string to `caracter`, the word read from the user may be incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

`&caracter` is the address of the pointer itself. It can be 2(AVR),4 or 8 bytes long. Using pointer as a char array makes no sense at all, but you can store there 1, 3, or 7 chars string.

`char *caracter;` defines an uninitialized pointer.

You need to allocate the memory for your string.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    srand(1); 
    int const numero=rand() % 9000 + 1000;
    char character[100];
    //or char *character = malloc(100);

    while (scanf("%99s",caracter)!=EOF){
        printf("%s",caracter); 
        printf("%i\n",numero);
    }
    return 0;
}
```